# Ruby - Convert a hash formatted array in to an actual hash

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and started using it for the last few days, so my apologies if I am asking something very basic.

I am looking for a way to convert the following array into a hash.

```
arr => 

{"id"=>"xxx", "name"=>"show all", "parent_id"=>"yyy", "tsuite_name"=>"show system", "tc_external_id"=>"zzz"}
```

where arr.length is 1.

I tried to workaround it but could not convert it as a hash.

I needed this because Testlink xmlrpc responds with the format shown above.

Any help on this would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Your array is already a hash or something is missing from you code

Comment: I think something is missing.  I don't see an array.

Comment: @Ray - The actual xmlrpc response was  "[{"id"=>"xxx", "name"=>"show all", "parent_id"=>"yyy", "tsuite_name"=>"show system", "tc_external_id"=>"zzz"}]"

Comment: Ah, okay then just take element 0 of the array and you will have your hash. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Ruby!

The below construct is a Hash.

```
{"id"=>"xxx", "name"=>"show all", "parent_id"=>"yyy", "tsuite_name"=>"show system", "tc_external_id"=>"zzz"}
```

If it was an Array, it would be surrounded by braces:

```
[{"id"=>"xxx", "name"=>"show all", "parent_id"=>"yyy", "tsuite_name"=>"show system", "tc_external_id"=>"zzz"}]
```

But what I think you were given was this:

```
{ "arr" => {"id"=>"xxx", "name"=>"show all", "parent_id"=>"yyy", "tsuite_name"=>"show system", "tc_external_id"=>"zzz"} }
```

The above object is a Hash within a Hash.  The `length` method reported 1 because the hash only contained a single key, namely, `arr`.

You can test the class of a variable with the `class` method:

```
$ irb
>> var = { "arr" => {"id"=>"xxx", "name"=>"show all" } }
=> { "arr" => {"id"=>"xxx", "name"=>"show all" } }
>> var.class
=> Hash
```

If all you need is the value of the inside hash, then grab it like so:

```
>> keep = var["arr"]
=> {"id"=>"xxx", "name"=>"show all" }
```

If I totally misunderstood your question, then please clarify.

Comment: Karrick - Thanks for the response. It was an array only, the output was surrounded by braces only as shown in your reply. Is there a way to convert that to a hash?

Comment: Sure, you can get any item from an Array using it's index inside braces, in other words `arr[0]`.  A common shortcut in Ruby is to use the `first` method to get the first item from an Array: `arr.first`.